# How to remove unwanted css and js from your django application?

Tags: css, django, css-purge

I'm making a Fullstack application which uses Django as a backend and javascript and jquery as a frontend.The app is finished now I want to remove unwanted css,images,js which just lie there in static files but are not used in templates is there a way to remove all of this unwanted code,files.I checked on the internet and there are solutions like purgecss but they use npm for running and I don't have npm
Is there any other way to it easily or if I have to do it by using purgecss.Can you guide me all the way in the answer section.

Thank you